# Circuitpython access point doesn't close

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi-pico, access-point, adafruit-circuitpython

when trying to close an access point I set up earlier, i get an error message as an output
im using following code on a Raspberry pi pico w

```
import time
import wifi

wifi.Radio.enabled: True
radio = wifi.radio

#setting up ssid, password, channel and authmode
ssid = 'RPPW'
password = 'RPPW1234'
channel = 1
authmode = (wifi.AuthMode.WPA2, wifi.AuthMode.PSK)

print('activating access point')
radio.start_ap(ssid, password, channel=channel, authmode=authmode)

time.sleep(10)

# Stop the access point
print('deactivating access point')
radio.stop_ap()
```

when running this code i recieve following output

```
activating access point
deactivating access point
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 20, in <module>
NotImplementedError: Stopping AP is not supported.
```

Thanks